# How much significant growth occurs on rest days?

Tags: recovery

After the moment you wake up after a workout day how much actual significant muscle growth occurs in the 24 hours ahead?

Or are rest days to prevent over training and full restoration of strength?

Answer (score -1):

Growth occurs during sleep time not while your muscles are awake and working to keep you walking around.

**If** you can gain 200 grams of muscle spread all over your body in one week thats 200÷7=28 grams each time you sleep.

This also depends on how often you train and how much working volume you do, both frequency  and bolume are key for muscle growth. The more the better as long as you start small and slowly increase both over time.

Comment: The 200 grams in a week part is very interesting. Where did you come across the whole 28 grams around the body thing? I'd like to learn more about that.

Comment: Its just the average muscle gained per week as seen on   novices, but I believe the numbers remain equal for advanced people too if progression is on par. https://www.theglobeandmail.com/life/health-and-fitness/fitness/muscle-gains-can-be-seen-after-a-few-weeks-of-hard-workouts-study/article34894516/

Comment: Also there would actually be no increase in mass if the person is in a plateau?

Comment: Growth requires progression. As long as you can do 1 repetition more than you did the last time or put half a kilogram more  on the bar, you will grow. Not progressing in strength will not only not make you grow but probably will make you lose muscle over the long run.